# What do we call the little cape that just covers the shoulder?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The Coneheads wore little capes that just covered the shoulders.

[image]

What's the word or phrase for these little doodads?

Comment: I've heard it called a mantle, but a little googling shows me that "mantle" can be used to describe a wider variety of garments.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since 1912 at least, they have been called '[capelets](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capelet)' according to Merriam-Webster online.

> capelet :  a small cape usually covering the shoulders

From the 14th century the word [tippet](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:qwHnttlObasJ:https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tippet%20&cd=18&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) seems to have been used.
Merriam-Webster defines Tippet

> 2 :  a shoulder cape of fur or cloth often with hanging ends

While I Marc Carlson's *Glossary of some medieval clothing terms* gives a lengthier description. (bolding mine)

[Tippet](http://www.personal.utulsa.edu/~marc-carlson/cloth/glossary.html)

[Origin uncertain; some suggest identity with OE. tæpped, tæppet, *teped (pl. tæppedu, tepedu) carpet, hanging, etc. = OHG. teppid, -ith, -it, tepid, -it: both ad. L. tapete (-a, -um) a carpet, tapestry hanging, bed-cover, table-cover. But there are great difficulties both of phonology and of sense. Others suggest a derivative of tip]  1. a. A long narrow slip of cloth or hanging part of dress, formerly worn, either attached to and forming part of the hood, head-dress, or sleeve, or loose, as a scarf or the like. **Obs. exc. Hist.b. A garment, usually of fur or wool, covering the shoulders, or the neck and shoulders; a cape or short cloak, often with hanging ends. Now worn chiefly by women and girls, or by men as a part of certain official costumes**.    In many early quots. (omitted here), senses a and b are not distinguishable.

Answer (score 5):

Since I believe this moment in the movie represents quasi-religious garb, I believe [pellegrina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pellegrina) is appropriate (although that is closely tied with the Catholic religion).

For the secular version, capelet or tippet is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen it called a **Shoulder Cape**, shown below on a nurse in the Australian Army Nursing Service working dress.

Other times, the cape may fit atop or into a heavy Western or Australian oilcloth coat for the cold and rain, called a duster.

[image: Australian Army Nursing Service]

Comment: The picture is nice, but do you have a link or something to show that people have called it a "shoulder cape"?

Comment: What do you use often -- your ear or your language or your shoulder cape?

Comment: I apologize if I offended. I was just trying to make a little joke.

Comment: FWIW that kind of coat is called a horseman's duster. They do generally have a capelet which I believe functions for rain run off (they are more typically made out of oilcloth to be waterproof--the leather one in the picture looks like a fashion remake).

Comment: In other words... change the image, so people will be less influenced/annoyed/bothered/irritated by it, and see that your suggestion is perfectly fine. E.g https://www.awm.gov.au/education/nurse-s-shoulder-cape/ and https://www.awm.gov.au/blog/2014/08/13/australian-army-nursing-service-aans-1914-1918-working-dress/

Comment: On a duster the 'capelet' is called a *storm flap*.

Answer (score -1):

A short cape is often called a **cowl**. Modern "cowls" are mostly overgrown scarves, but if you look up "medieval cowl" you will see shoulder-length cloaks, usually with hoods. Not all of them open at the front, as in the picture, but some do.
A poncho is similar, but I believe a **poncho** is always a single piece in the front, rather than tied. A **shawl** is also similar, but I would argue a shawl is usually the product of needlework (rather than sewn fabric pieces). A **capelet** could probably encompass any of these.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.  Please check your research as these terms are not clear.  I hope you take a moment to take the [tour] and see [how to write a good answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), as this may help you improve your post.

Comment: Can something be a cowl if it doesn't have a hood? I don't think so, and except for certain religious mediaeval garments, [the dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cowl) seems to agree with me.

Answer (score -1):

The term we use in America is Cape. I happen to be an avid unintentional collector of quite a few .  I also have numerous Shawls. The difference between the two is shawls are generally longer & thinner & material. The shawl just drapes your back near shoulder blades and rest near the anticubital area. Where as a cape sits on your shoulders. Lengths of capes I've came across personally can be as short in length just past shoulders or as long to the knees.
Someone above mentioned a cowell that is totally different due to the fact the garmet is a circle meant to wear around the neck without having to tie hence the ends are sewn together. Often made with angora.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).