# English word for this type of clothes?

Tags: word-choice

I have seen two examples from Japanese media where males wear this sort of tunic thing but I can't find the name for it, does anyone know the name?

See video: https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV16J411z78G/

[image: Kaito from Cantarella]

Answer (score 21):

It looks like a stylised version of the caped '[greatcoat](https://candicehern.com/regencyworld/french-gentlemans-greatcoat-march-1811/)' worn in the (British) Regency period.

Comment: The thing the Johnny’s Juniors are wearing (from the bilibili video) is the same thing but without the cape?

Comment: The dancers are wearing coats inspired by 19th century European men's fashions.

Answer (score 17):

Apparently, the term **Inverness cape** (/'Inverness Greatcoat') has been used for a similar if less flamboyant British garment:

[image]

Mans Single Breasted English Regency Inverness Greatcoat Victorian [[Etsy](https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/205035977/mans-single-breasted-english-regency)]

Etsy may be misusing the term to describe their remarkable garment shown above, although [LynOakes](https://www.lynoakes.co.uk/inverness-cape.html) default to a cape-length hidden sleeve, negotiable with the buyer ... as Tonny agrees in a comment below. Wikipedia limits the term to sleeveless caped greatcoats:

> The *Inverness cape* is a form of weatherproof outer-coat. It is notable
> for being sleeveless, the arms emerging from armholes beneath a cape.
> It has become associated with the fictional detective Sherlock Holmes.

[[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverness_cape)]

Comment: The picture shows a "standard" Greatcoat with (fixed or detachable) cape, while the "Inverness" variant has no sleeves at all or very short sleeves that are completely covered by the cape.

Comment: Note that you won't get that dramatic flare at the bottom, unless the guy just did a little spin before that shot was taken.  I suppose you could put some sort of wire mesh inside like those old bustles that Victorian women wore, but that's not very commonly seen in men's clothing as far as I'm aware.

Comment: No. As @Kate puts it so well, the Japanese variant is a 'stylised' version. Holmes wouldn't have found it easy examining clues on the ground in such a garment. But one might have been useful at Reichenbach.

Answer (score 14):

It is a Robe or Coat.

Since it is so elaborate, I would call it a Greatcoat (with cape)

[image]

Comment: I think he's looking a bit too cheerful for that coat :)

Comment: Definitely, way to cheerful. He looks like he's posing for his mum to take a photo of him in his new uniform, before his first day at work.

Comment: Streange, I'm finding peacoats when I'm searcing for greatcoat.

Answer (score 5):

By "short tunic thing" I guess you mean the top part that goes down to the level of his elbows.  If so, it is a "cape" as mentioned by Kate.  Capes can also be longer than this one, see Superman.

Comment: ***capelet*** if it's detachable. ***storm flap*** if it isn't. Altogether, if it's Australian oilcloth, it's called a [**duster**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/377639/68817).

Comment: The question says "sort of tunic thing", not "short tunic thing".

Comment: "see Superman" -> I tried but all I see are birds and planes... :(

Answer (score 1):

A greatcoat with integral cape is (or was — no one has worn it except as cosplay for over a century) is called a Garrick coat or “carrick” coat (apparently a [French mispronunciation of Garrick](https://candicehern.com/regencyworld/french-gentlemans-greatcoat-march-1811/) that came back to the UK) or a coachman’s coat.

Although it started with only one cape, apparently it became fashionable to have two, three, as many as ten capes attached — with buttons, in a rare show of sartorial sanity, that allowed them to be removed when the weather was less inclement.

Comment: Please add supporting references; this sounds too good an answer not to be upvoted.